# Question ruled as off topic, should not be so

Tags: discussion

What are the benefits of being outspoken? [on hold]
[What are the benefits of being outspoken?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63781/what-are-the-benefits-of-being-outspoken)

It is a discussion of navigating the workplace and using the soft-skill of ensuring that one is recognized for their work and how to defend against those who might steal work.

Similarly, THIS question was not voted as off topic.
[How do I positively acknowledge a mistake I made to my manager?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63777/how-do-i-positively-acknowledge-an-mistake-i-made-to-my-manager)

Both are asking for how to deal with specific work-place difficulties.  The only real difference I see between the two is that the former was perhaps worded a bit more gruffly, but no less relevant.

Comment: Seconded, the first question is not about company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies. They were asking the benefit of being outspoken in the workplace, a perfectly valid question as some people are introverted and some are extroverted and the pros/cons of each are open to analysis.

Comment: The title might be part of the problem; it sure sounds like an open-ended opinion question from that.  I think there's an interesting question under there about deciding when and how to adopt norms that aren't your own but that your boss seems to want; I'm not sure the current revision brings that out enough.  (I also realize this reaction is vague; best I can do right now, sorry.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thank you.  You obviously game this thought and an honest answer is always appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The [What are the benefits of being outspoken?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63781/what-are-the-benefits-of-being-outspoken) question is a rant in disguise.

It is basically, "I think my coworker is a jerk, please let me know if he's a jerk or not, it's so unfair." There is no problem to be solved, just opinions looking to be validated. That is not a good fit for a Q/A but more a discussion board/chat environment.

In other words, there is no "here's the situation, how do I do X to cause Y?" question instead it is "situation X sucks, right!?"

Contrast that to the duplicate link which has a much more constructive problem and looking for specific actionable answers.

I do think that someone could [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/63781/edit) the question and make it more on topic by removing the rantiness and focusing on what might be a core question, but right now it is a rant. Joe's response applies too. Some companies/cultures/bosses will "reward" this more than others.

Answer (score 4):

> What are the benefits of being outspoken? [on hold] What are the
>   benefits of being outspoken?
>
> It is a discussion of navigating the workplace and using the
>   soft-skill of ensuring that one is recognized for their work and how
>   to defend against those who might steal work.

While I didn't vote to close the question, in my answer I provided my reason as to why the question isn't really answerable from my point of view:

"It depends on the local culture, the specific job, and the specific organization. And it depends on the specifics of what being a "big mouth" means in each case."

Comment: Given that the person in question's native tongue was not English, I think he deserves a bit of latitude, and while there are variations from culture to culture, how universal do answers need to be to be of use?

Comment: RichardU: one of the difference between SE and other q&a sites is that SE has aspirations of becoming a crowdsourced FAQ site. As such, there is a stronger emphasis on reusable answers here than elsewhere, and some effort to shape questions toward that end.